# Recursion inside another func causes bad access

Tags: recursion, swift

I had the following code:

```
func pi() -> Double {
    func iteration(denominator: Double) -> Double {
        let nextNumber: Double = 1.0 / denominator
        let isPreciseEnough = abs(nextNumber) < 0.0002

        if isPreciseEnough {
            return nextNumber
        }
        let newDenominator = (abs(denominator) + 2.0) * denominator / abs(denominator) * -1.0
        return nextNumber + iteration(newDenominator)
    }
    return 4.0 * iteration(1.0)
}
```

When I ran it, it stopped with bad access at the second run in playground, and when I tried to build it in a project, it stopped with

> "swift failed with exit code 1"

I checked the value of denominator and it was **2.23690525377983e-314** at the second run. However, when I separated the methods like

```
func pi() -> Double {
    return 4.0 * iteration(1.0)
}

func iteration(denominator: Double) -> Double {
    let nextNumber: Double = 1.0 / denominator
    let isPreciseEnough = abs(nextNumber) < 0.0002

    if isPreciseEnough {
        return nextNumber
    }
    let newDenominator = (abs(denominator) + 2.0) * denominator / abs(denominator) * -1.0
    return nextNumber + iteration(newDenominator)
}
```

it worked perfectly. Can anyone explain, why the example on the top doesn't work?

Comment: +1: I didn't realize it was valid to place a `func` inside a `func`, but the compiler doesn't complain. I see the same behavior you do.

Comment: When I try this in an Xcode 6.1 Playground I get a **compile** error when trying to call `iteration` recursively: `Local functions cannot reference themselves`.

Comment: @MikeS I'm pretty late, but if you make an answer from the comment, I will accept it as an answer.